PKCanvasView not showing when added as a subview
I am trying to integrate the PKCanvasView to a React Native app but when I try to add the canvasView as a subView it doesn't show. It only works if I return it directly.
Here is my code.
// BBNativePencilManager.swift
// import PencilKit;

@objc(BBNativePencilManager)
class BBNativePencilManager: RCTViewManager {
  override func view() -> UIView {
//    let canvasView = PKCanvasView();
//    let drawing = PKDrawing()
//    canvasView.drawing = drawing;
//    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
//      canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
//    }
//    if (theme == "dark") {
//      canvasView.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark;
//    } else {
//      canvasView.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light;
//    }
//    canvasView.isOpaque = false;
//    canvasView.backgroundColor = .clear;
//    canvasView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true;
//    canvasView.backgroundColor = .yellow
//    canvasView.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: UIColor.black, width: 5)
//    canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
//    return canvasView;
//    The above code works correctly
    return BBNativePencilView(); // <-- this does not work
  }
  
  override static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}


And the BBNativePencilView
// BBNativePencilView.swift
import UIKit
import PencilKit


class BBNativePencilView: UIView {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addSubview(canvas)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  
  lazy var canvas: PKCanvasView = {
    let canvasView = PKCanvasView()
    let drawing = PKDrawing.init()
    canvasView.drawing = drawing;
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
      canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
    }
    canvasView.isOpaque = false;
    canvasView.backgroundColor = .clear;
    canvasView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true;
    canvasView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    canvasView.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: UIColor.black, width: 5)
    canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
    return canvasView;
  }()
}


Could someone explain the issue to me? Thank you!

This might be due to layout or frame issues when adding it as a subview.
Ensure that the BBNativePencilView frame and the canvas frame are properly set. The canvas may not be visible if its frame is incorrectly set or too small.
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    canvas.frame = self.bounds;
    canvas.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight];
    self.addSubview(canvas);
  }

